# Settingup Login using AngularJS and NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to setup the login page for my **ADMINISTRATOR** app using AngularJS and NodeJS.
I have a hard coded username and password in the Mongo Database that looks like this:

```
{
    "userName": "david",
    "password": "hello123"
}
```

Right now it's very simple, if I insert in the login form:
username: *john*
password: *bye123*
the output(in the console) is `user doesn't exist!`
now if I insert to the login form:
username: *david*
password: *hello123*
the output is- `logged in succesfully`  OK that's good.

Now I'm looking for a way to make my app secure, maybe using token or something like that. I'm not so familiar with these methods.
I would like a code example or explanation of where to put the security code in my app.

#### The following is the controller on client side:

signInController.js

```
 app.controller('signInController', function ($scope, $http) {
            $.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
                         options.async = true;});
   $scope.signing = function (user) {

    console.log('in sign in');

    if ($scope.inForm.$valid) {

            console.log('after validation');

             var data = $.param({
            userName : user.userName,
            password : user.password
        });
                var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                    }
                }
        $http.post('/admin/signIn', data, config)
                      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                       $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
                       console.log( data);
                       console.log('after login');

                window.location.replace('#/dashboard');
                console.log("Success");
            })
                        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                            console.log("Error: "+data);
                            $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                                "<hr />status: " + status +
                                "<hr />headers: " + header +
                                "<hr />config: " + config;
             });  
     }             
}});
```

#### The following is the controller on server side:

user.controller.js

```
    var qs = require('querystring');
    var User = require('../models/User');
    module.exports = {
       signIn: signIn
   }

   function signIn(req, res) {
          console.log("get post request in server side");  

    var body = '';
      req.on('data', function (data) {
           body += data;
           // 1e6 === 1 * Math.pow(10, 6) === 1 * 1000000 ~~~ 1MB
           if (body.length > 1e6) { 
              // FLOOD ATTACK OR FAULTY CLIENT, NUKE REQUEST
              req.connection.destroy();
          }
     });   
     req.on('end', function () {
     var POST = qs.parse(body); 
     var existUser = new User({ userName : POST.userName,password :  POST.password });
            User.findOne({  userName: existUser.userName}, function (err, user) {
              if (user) {

                if(user.password != existUser.password)
                {
                       res.send("Incorrect password");
                }
                else
                {

                    res.send("logged in succesfully");
                }

           }
            else {
                console.log(user);
                res.send("user doesn't exist!");
            }
        });

    });}
```

#### and this is what my user model looks like:

User.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema= mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',{

    userName : String,
    password : String
  });
```

Comment: For what it's worth, don't reinvent the wheel ;) Check out http://passportjs.org

Comment: Take a look at this generator as an example:

https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack

Comment: Do you use bcrypt for storing password?